# PHPMYAdmin FREEZES when applying Trigger

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using  this following trigger

```
DELIMITER ;
CREATE TRIGGER updateCount
 AFTER INSERT ON user_info
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

UPDATE users SET counter=counter+1 WHERE users.id = (SELECT `user_info`.`bookmark_id` from `user_info` WHERE user_info.id = NEW.id) ;

END;
//
delimiter ;
```

EDIT :

i also used this

```
   delimiter // 
    CREATE TRIGGER updateCount
     AFTER INSERT ON user_info
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

    UPDATE users SET counter=counter+1 WHERE users.id = (SELECT `user_info`.`bookmark_id` from `user_info` WHERE user_info.id = NEW.id) ;

    END;
    //
    delimiter ;
```

This is working fine on my local . but on live phpmyadmin freezes

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: *Hm....*, not entirely sure, but using a semi-colon as a delimiter may not be a good idea. Try using something else. `;` is a PHP end of script directive.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's exactly what's wrong here.

Comment: what should i use . please explain

Comment: @HituBansal I always use `DELIMITER //`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html same example in there as @Daan uses.

Comment: @Daan: i used  // stil it freezed

Comment: @HituBansal I answered your question that should work for you.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's not true you need to change it back to `;`

Comment: `END;` should be `END //`

Comment: @Daan You are way too fast lol I deleted my comment about that before I saw your comment; again lol second time in a week? hahaha

Comment: Run an explain query as `explain SELECT user_info.bookmark_id from user_info WHERE user_info.id = some userid` and share the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS updateCount//
CREATE TRIGGER updateCount
 AFTER INSERT ON user_info
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

UPDATE users SET counter=counter+1 WHERE users.id = (SELECT `user_info`.`bookmark_id` from `user_info` WHERE user_info.id = NEW.id);

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: It should give an error, which one is it? Try to insert a record into `user_info` with phpmyadmin it will give you an error.

Comment: after 10 mins, it gave me error. Could not process the request , Error code 500

Comment: That is an http error it means you have an internal server error.

Comment: Why it is taking 10 mintues to execute trigger command. on local it was very Quick

Comment: Because locally you aren't connected to HTTP.

Comment: So, what is the best way to implement trigger on that

Comment: This has nothing todo with your trigger, it has to do with either your internet connection (slow) or the servers internet connection, you should ask a different question for this.

Comment: @HituBansal Error code 500 is a server error as Daan said. If you have access to your (error) logs, see what they say.

Comment: @HituBansal So, what's the score; anything in your logs?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the delimiters would cause the trigger to hang.

Do you have indexes on `user_info(id)` and `users(id)`?

An alternative possibility is that `users` is locked for some reason.